# lose socket io connection in cordova app on ios when standby

Tags: ios, cordova, socket.io

I build a cordova app that use socket io. On ios, when the phone enter in standby I am losing the socket connection. How can I detect that and reconnect the socket connection automatically?

Comment: Here is a similar problem to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708604/nodejs-socket-io-connections-dropping-reconnecting

Comment: I don't think it is similar because that's not depend on idle time, if push the standby button on the phone, the phone enter directly in stand by and i am losing the connection

Comment: Yeah, looking around this is a problem that they are dealing with.  They had some potentially successful results using TCP when using VOIP.  It is a different library but maybe it can help you out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601536/ios-voip-socket-will-not-run-in-background

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this @RaphaelBoukara

Comment: I actually just discovered some very interesting behavior that I did not expect, and it seems to solve my issue as well. Including the [cordova-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) plugin and enabling it keeps my socket connection open. handling other functions and events in my app shouldn't be a problem, the problem was just keeping the socket connection open. all I had to do was enable the background mode with cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable() and it works, I didn't even have to set functions to run in the onactivate event.