# WebRTC signaling server Websocket connection closed in Chrome

Tags: node.js, webrtc, signaling

I managed to deploy the WebRTC signaling server (https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster). And there is only one problem remaining
For some reason, the connection does not work in Chrome. Chrome throws a warning:

```
WebSocket connection to '<wss://.......:8888/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=-OpElfbpa4_ZAGS9AAAK>' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Hovewer it works fine in Firefox. 
I set up the SSL certificates. Signaling server is running on EC2.
Do you have any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: To get more information try to debug socket.io and see if you can catch why the socket is being closed. You can use: `DEBUG=* node app.js` in server side or `localStorage.debug = '*';` in client side. See more on how to debug in this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_logging_and_debugging.htm).

Update your question if you find something suspicious so we can better help :).

Comment: @elbecita here is a pastebin with output on server https://pastebin.com/8YfrBsY4
and the client output http://prntscr.com/gvozyc

Comment: Don't see anything relevant that helps identifying why the connection is closed. I answered with a few things to try. Let me know if any of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try that might solve the issue:

- Are socket.io and socket.io-client the same version? If not, you should set them to the same version and try, since a mismatch can cause unstable behavior.
- Try to modify the ping interval and the pong timeout, to detect if it is due to a timeout in the heartbeats because it takes longer on Chrome. You can do this with:

`const io = require('socket.io')(http, {'pingInterval': 5000, 'pingTimeout': 10000});`

(This would be 5 seconds interval and 10 seconds timeout, feel free to tweak this and see if it affects somehow).

- Related to heartbeats check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33482143/4067893) too. Might be that there is no activity in the socket and thus socket.io closes the connection.
- Another thing to check logs: while you are trying to establish the webrtc connection, open a new tab and go to [chrome://webrtc-internals/](http://chrome://webrtc-internals/) and see if you can check what is going on. If there are ICE Candidates, if not, if there is a pair of selected candidates, etc.

I hope some of this information helps.